# Add zero-padding to a string

Tags: c#, string, padding

How do I add "0" padding to a string so that my string length is always 4?

Example

```
If input "1", 3 padding is added = 0001
If input "25", 2 padding is added = 0025
If input "301", 1 padding is added = 0301
If input "4501", 0 padding is added = 4501
```

Answer (score 365, accepted):

You can use [PadLeft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/66f6d830.aspx)

```
var newString = Your_String.PadLeft(4, '0');
```

Comment: Keep in mind that `"12345".PadLeft(4,'0')` is _still_ "12345" - it won't truncate it. This doesn't detract from this answer by the way since it meets all the specs (there's something strangely satisfying about having an answer you upvoted chosen as the accepted one (though not as satisfying as having one of your own accepted of course), sort of like your son getting into the best school), just thought I'd mention it in case it reared its ugly head sometime in the future. Cripes, I hope those parentheses are balanced :-)

Comment: @paxdiablo: They were until the smiley.

Comment: `"1.2".PadRight(4,'0')` also works for zero filling a string number such as "1.20". I can do this to truncate and fill a simple string number < 10000.  `num = num.length > 4 ? num.Substring(0,4) : num.PadRight(4,'0');`

Answer (score 75):

```
myInt.ToString("D4");
```

Comment: The question is how to add padding "to a string."

Comment: `string.Format("{0:D4}", myInt)`

Answer (score 43):

```
string strvalue="11".PadRight(4, '0');
```

output= 1100

```
string strvalue="301".PadRight(4, '0');
```

output= 3010

```
string strvalue="11".PadLeft(4, '0');
```

output= 0011

```
string strvalue="301".PadLeft(4, '0');
```

output= 0301

Answer (score 11):

```
"1".PadLeft(4, '0');
```

Answer (score 5):

```
int num = 1;
num.ToString("0000");
```

Answer (score 0):

with `sed`

- always add three leading zeroes
- then trim to 4 digits

```
sed -e 's/^/000/;s/^0*\([0-9]\{4,\}\)$/\1/'
```