# Get string with constant length - lead with zeros

Tags: c#, string-formatting

What is the easiest way to put some zeroes at the beginning of a string?

For example I have a string and I want to have it have a fixed length of 10 characters, so it should be `0000string`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Add zero-padding to a string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3122677/add-zero-padding-to-a-string)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`PadLeft`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/92h5dc07%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

```
string result = myString.PadLeft(10, '0');
```

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
string str= youstr.PadLeft(10, '0');
```

PadLeft:

> Returns a new string that right-aligns the characters in this instance
>   by padding them on the left with a specified Unicode character, for a
>   specified total length.