# Transforming a string using Regex C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, regex, transform

i've been kicking my self for a while now with regex, and unable to find a proper solution. I've been trying to transform a string using Regex.Replace() method in C# which should prepend 0 to existing string if length is less than 5, the conversion might be as follow

```
Input String ----------- Output String
12345        ----------- 12345
123          ----------- 00123
123456       ----------- 123456
```

any help will be appreciated

Comment: Are these the actual input strings, or just the numbers contained within a bigger block of text?

Comment: does it have to be `Regex`? if not try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3122677/add-zero-padding-to-a-string

Comment: Guys it has to be Regex... and '-' is not included in the input just used it for formatting

Comment: Why use regex if framework already provides function specifically for that purpose ?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [String.PadLeft](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/92h5dc07%28v=vs.110%29.aspx): `"1234".PadLeft(5, '0')`

Comment: shouldn't it be `"1234".PadLeft(5, '0')`

Comment: Whatever number he pleases ;)

Comment: I take your point, but, OP stated "....if length is less than 5". (I think SO is making a pedant out of me!) : )

Comment: Changed it to correct number ;)

Answer (score 1):

It can be like

```
var outputString = Regex.Replace(inputString, @"\d+", n => n.Value.PadLeft(5, '0'));
```

but you don't really need regex in this case.

Comment: Regex is just overkill here. But OP wanted that way so ....:)

Comment: wow couldn't have figured out without ur help :P ... anyways i think there is no way left just to change the code

Answer (score 0):

You don't need any regex

```
if(str.Length < 5){
  for(var i = 0; i < 5 - str.length; i++)
      str = "0" + str;
}
```

The above is all you need. What you're doing is if the input string's Length is less than 5, you're just subtracting and looping, adding them.

Comment: @MirzaTalha Why? Why place artificial restrictions on a solution?

Comment: @mason because i don't want to change my code... it will result in re-deployment of the existing application

Comment: @MirzaTalha If you're asking for us to provide a regex, that means you're having to change the code anyways. Might as well use the proper tools for the job. Regex should only be used when there's absolutely no better option.

Comment: @mason The regex is configurable from a configuration file, that is why i was asking for regex mate