# How padding 2 variable on c#?

Tags: c#, pad

```
  function zeroPad(num, places){
        var zero = places - num.toString().length + 1;
        return Array(+(zero > 0 && zero)).join("0") + num;
    }
```

Please tell me the means of code above, and how to use it on C#

Comment: Thats JavaScript to add *n* leading zeros... For C# cast to string & use `.PadLeft` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3122677/add-zero-padding-to-a-string

Comment: Don't add "[tag]Solved[/tag]" to your title, accept the answer.

Answer (score 1):

The code is Javascript and pads the number `num` with zeros to the length `places`, for example `zeroPad(12, 4)` gives you `0012`. In C# you can do this with the `PadLeft()` method, for example `12.ToString().PadLeft(4, '0')` which gives you the same as above `0012`.

Comment: If padding is fixed and always `0` is acceptable: easier to use `12.ToString("0000")`

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti Right, for numbers that is simpler. `PadLeft()` works for all kind of strings and padding characters.

Comment: Yes, that's why I added as comment: it's just a non general special case