# Convert string type to 8 digit in c#

Tags: c#

I need to convert this value to 8 digit format. (example : 1 --> 00000001).any help? here's my code

```
foreach(DataRow dr in _dsGridCsv.Tables[0].Rows)
  {           
     byte empfrmat =byte.Parse(dr["emp_id"].ToString());
     csv += empfrmat;
     csv += "\r\n";
  }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C# convert int to string with padding zeros?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4325267/c-sharp-convert-int-to-string-with-padding-zeros)

Comment: Why do you parse to byte and then again to string?

Comment: my mistake. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

1. By using padLeft

   eg. `"1".PadLeft(8, '0');`

Ref. [Add zero-padding to a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3122677/add-zero-padding-to-a-string)

Answer (score 1):

strValue.ToString("D8");

D8 means format as a decimal with up to 8 leading zeroes

Answer (score 0):

So you want to change the value to 8 digit format, according to the example that you specified, you can try the following code for this:

```
int value = 1;
String outputStr = value.ToString("00000000");
Console.WriteLine(outputStr) // this will print 00000001
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. worked for me. the major problem was I save this values to a csv file which opens with excel. so even this converted successfully, the result won't show in the format that i wanted. so need to find a solution for that.