# Add zero padding to string in c?

Tags: c

The concept is very similar to this [Add zero-padding to a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3122677/add-zero-padding-to-a-string) but it's a question from c# NOT C.

While you can add a zero padding in printf like this `printf("%4d", number)`

How can I have a zero padding to a string? ex:

```
char *file_frame = "shots";
strcat(file_frame, "%3d", number); // It's my attempt to solve it. I know it's wrong
```

so that I would get `shots000` from `file_frame`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `sprintf`

```
sprintf(file_frame, "%04d", 34);
```

The `0` indicates what you are padding with and the `4` shows the length of the integer number.

---

Also you should be using mutable array as below.

```
char *file_frame = "shots"; --> char file_frame[100] = "shots";
```

Answer (score 1):

First you need some space to store the string. Then you "print" into this string:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {
    char file_name[8 + 1]; // "shots###" is 8 characters, plus 1 for end-of-string marker '\0'
    int number = 23;
    sprintf(file_name, "shots%03d", number);

    printf("\"%s\"\n", file_name);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

You can combine literal parts with formatting parts in any `*printf()` function.

Answer (score -1):

Well, this is the workaround I did: -

```
char output[9];
char buffer[9];

itoa(num, output, 2);
int i=0;
for (i=0; i<(8-strlen(output));i++) {
    buffer[i]='0';
}
for(int j=0;j<strlen(output);j++){
    buffer[i] = output[j];
    i++;
}
```

Input:-

```
num = 10
```

Output: -

```
buffer = 00001010
```